# SQL - Closest rows to Now() but unique

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am having a slight issue.  I have 2 tables, one contains the merchant information, name etc and another contains Events.

1. I upload prices to the event table every few days so there is a lot of duplicate content only distinguished through its TIMESTAMP column(Uploaddate).
2. I need to select the prices for the most recent uploads and therefore the others not to   be selected.

   > ```
   > Event
   > name    date            price      merchant
   > test    2012-02-26      £10        ShopX
   > test    2012-02-26      £11        ShopY
   > test    2012-02-26      £9         ShopX     -   LATEST PRICE
   > ```

   IE. Select prices which are the most up-to-date and make sure each merchant is unique, so only 1 price per merchant.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_events, wp_merchants
WHERE DATE =  '2012-02-26'
AND eventname =  'testevent'
AND  `uploaddate` > NOW( ) 
AND wp_events.merchant = wp_merchants.merchant_name
ORDER BY uploaddate DESC
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  also if you are looking for uploaddate > now(), that appears to be looking for records in the future, I wouldn't think you would have records with an upload date greater than the current.

Comment: hi yes, I have changed uploaddate > now() to uploaddate < now() but it lists all the uploaddates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX()` in a subquery, which will look something like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(DATE), event, merchant
FROM
  someTable
GROUP BY
  event, merchant
```

Next, incorporate the subquery into a main query to get the latest price (I guess that's what you want):

```
SELECT
  someTable.price, someTable.event, someTable.merchant
FROM
  someTable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(DATE) AS DATE, event, merchant
    FROM
      someTable
    GROUP BY
      event, merchant
  ) subquery
  ON someTable.DATE = subquery.DATE AND someTable.event = subquery.event AND someTable.merchant = subquery.merchant
```

I haven't verified the code.

Comment: im struggling to implement this actually, maybe confused or its too late at night.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
select e1.merchant, e1.price from event e1
left join event e2
on (e1.merchant = e2.merchant and e1.date < e2.date)
where e2.merchant is null
```

This will get you this result:

```
+----------+-------+
| MERCHANT | PRICE |
+----------+-------+
| ShopY    | £11   |
| ShopX    | £9    |
+----------+-------+
```

So, you'll have to add the joins and filters you need.

**Edit:**

Isn't this what you're looking for?

```
select e1.merchant, e1.price from wp_events e1
left join wp_events e2
on (e1.merchant = e2.merchant and e1.uploaddate < e2.uploaddate)
where e2.merchant is null
```

Comment: Still can't figure it out even with 3 examples:


I have 2 Tables but cannot work out.. 
_________________
    'wp_events
    eventname
    date
    merchant
    price
    uploaddate

__________________________
   wp_merchants
   merchant_name
   merchantrating
   merchantlogo'

Comment: @mostly-mostacho Can you please explain further? Thanks