# SQL Select Newest Records based on Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 Tables, wp_events and wp_merchants.

I have many duplicated rows in the wp_events table, the only difference is the column uploaddate(TIMESTAMP) of when the record was added to the database.  I need an SQL statement that selects the prices from the wp_events table but if there are duplicates select the most recent.

This is what I have so far but not all records are selected.

```
SELECT e1.merchant, e1.price, e1.url, wp_merchants.merchant_logo, wp_merchants.merchant_name, e1.eventname
FROM wp_merchants, wp_events e1
LEFT JOIN wp_events e2 ON ( e1.merchant = e2.merchant
AND e1.uploaddate < e2.uploaddate ) 
WHERE e2.merchant IS NULL 
AND wp_merchants.merchant_name = e1.merchant
ORDER BY price ASC
```

PLEASE SEE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1db0e/1

Comment: Your query (if not optimal), looks like it returns exactly what you described it should. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270420/sql-closest-rows-to-now-but-unique ? Actually it is the same query I provided and you didn't mark as accepted, although it solves the problem.

Comment: hi yes, but for some reason after inputting more rows there seems to be a problem. thanks for looking.. Please see: ticketreview.net/festival-tickets/european-festivals/… 

This lists 3 results from the same merchant (WTS) however your query and the one above only selects 3 out of a possible 4. Hence no WTS in the result.. –

Comment: Ive added the fields to:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1871/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT e.merchant, e.price, e.url, m.merchant_logo, m.merchant_name, e.eventname
FROM wp_events e
INNER JOIN wp_merchants m 
ON e.merchant = m.merchant_name
AND e.uploaddate = (SELECT MAX(uploaddate) FROM wp_events WHERE merchant = e.merchant AND eventname = e.eventname)
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Please check and see if this is what you meant.

Comment: thanks for looking.. Please see:

http://www.ticketreview.net/festival-tickets/european-festivals/rock-im-park-festival-2012-weekend-tickets-tickets-at-zeppelinfeld-01-june-2012-buy-your-2012-festival-tickets-now/


It lists 3 results from the same merchant yet this query only selects 3 out of a possible 4. Hence no WTS in the result..

Comment: I have updated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1871/2 to show what I mean, the correct results are not returned. Please can you take 2mins to look.

Comment: it only returns 2 results for some reason. There are 4 different results that it should return. Not sure why it isnt though.

Comment: That's because there are some merchant rows missing from the wp_merchants table. Because an INNER JOIN is used, these rows are ignored. In your live version, these entries will most likely exist and it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the RDBMS you're using, it's possible you could use ROW_NUMBER() so you don't have to join a table to itself or use a subquery. This should work in SQL Server, Oracle, or PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT e.merchant AS merchant_name, e.price, e.url, e.event_name, m.merchant_logo
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.merchant ORDER BY e.uploaddate DESC) as the_row
      FROM wp_events e
     INNER JOIN wp_merchants m
        ON e.merchant = m.merchant_name
    ) WHERE the_row = 1
 ORDER BY price ASC
```

If you're using MySQL then you'll have to use another method.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it is in fact MySQL I am using.